# Converting $\cos(px/q)$ to $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm curious if we can find a form for $\cos(px/q)$ in terms of only $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$. I did some searching here and came up across this beautiful approach:

"Let $\cos(x) = c$, so $\sin(x) =  \pm\sqrt{1-c^2}$ and $\exp(\pm ix) = c \pm i \sqrt{1-c^2} $ (not necessarily with the same $+$ and $-$).  Then $\exp(\pm ipx/q) = (c \pm i \sqrt{1-c^2})^{p/q}$ so
$$ \cos(px/q) = \frac{\exp(ipx/q) + \exp(-ipx/q)}{2} = \frac{ (c + i \sqrt{1-c^2})^{p/q} + (c - i \sqrt{1-c^2})^{p/q}}{2}$$

Of course the multi-valued nature of the $p/q$ power of complex numbers must be taken into account."

\bib{4504784}{misc}{
title={$\cos\left(\frac pq x\right)$, $p\in\mathbb Z$ and $q\in\mathbb N$ to $f(\cos x)$},
author={Robert Israel (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel)}

However, when we have let's say $\cos(4x/3)$ then at $x=π$, this is $-1/2$ but the derived expression yields $1$. I think I am definitely missing something here, could someone please explain this?

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted? :( I just asked a question that has been bothering me for a while.

Comment: Maybe include the approach in your actual post, so that people don't have to go read another website to understand your question.

Comment: Done, sorry for not including it previously.

Comment: As your question said, you have to take into account the multivalued nature of the $p/q$ power. So instead of saying "... but the derived expression yields $1$",  it should be "... but the derived expression yields the following values: $1,\cdots$". If none of the **several** values obtained turns out to be $-1/2$ then you can begin to look for a mistake.

Comment: Oh! What do you mean by that, though? Could you please explain how we could get diiferent values using this expression?

Comment: In your example you set $p/q=4/3$ and $x=\pi$. That means that $c=\cos(x)=-1$, and $\sqrt{1-c^2} = 0$. So the expression you need to calculate is $\frac{(-1)^{4/3}+(-1)^{4/3}}{2}$ but it turns out that $(-1)^{4/3}$ has three possible values: $1$, $\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. To make things worse, there's no warranty that the "first" $(-1)^{4/3}$ and the "second" $(-1)^{4/3}$ will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there exists a function $f(u,v)$ such that (for example) $\cos(\tfrac{x}{2}) = f(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ for all $x$.

Then for $x=0$ we get $$1=\cos(\tfrac{0}{2}) = f(\cos(0),\sin(0)) = f(1,0)$$
and for $x=2\pi$ we get $$-1=\cos(\tfrac{2\pi}{2}) = f(\cos(2\pi),\sin(2\pi)) = f(1,0)$$

So $1 = f(1,0) = -1$, a contradiction.

This shows that no such function can exists that works for all $x$.

Of course, there are functions that work for certain subsets. For example, the well know formula $\cos(\tfrac{x}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}}$ works for $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$.

Be aware however that, in general, such formulas may be doesn't exist even for reduced domains, since finding a formula for $\cos(x/q)$ in terms of $\cos$ and $\sin$ is equivalent to solving a $q$-degree polynomial equation, and that is not always possible.